# Adding Chapter Subtitle

Tags: chapters

I would like to include a chapter subtitle line (not included in ToC) immediately below the chapter name, and I cannot get any of the few recommendations I've found to jive with my existing code for the chapter title layout. Any suggestions? Many thanks! (If it helps, I was trying to get my chapter headings to exclude the words "Chapter N" and to be centered.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{plain}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\LARGE\center}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter}{with your idea of how to make this happen}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{plain}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\LARGE\center}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter[This is a chapter]{This is a chapter\\{\large  with not so long sub title}}
    
\end{document}
```

Fist page:

[image]

Third page (the second is empty):

[image]

The content of the '[]' is the **short title** of the chapter (for TOC and heather/footer).

The content of the external couple of '{}' is the **long title** that I have dropped (with the double backslash) in two parts: the title and the subtitle (with the smaller chars).

**EDIT** If You want the subtitle emphasized consider this change:

```
\chapter[This is a chapter]{This is a chapter\\{\large \emph{ with not so long sub title}}}
```

Comment: This worked great; thank you! Is there an easy way to change the style of just the second line? I'd like it not to be bolded, but use \emph.

Comment: @jejwood Look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing this but getting no changes. I have tried placing \normalfont just before \emph, and now it is working. Apparently my preamble definitions of the formatting were overriding any changes here. Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @jejwood Great! Now You could accept my answer!